# HTML downloader and parser for CR

Tags: java, html, parsing, regex, web-scraping

This program downloads a Code Review HTML file and parses it.

Could you review my program?

Main.java

```
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String site1 = "http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/";
        String site2;
        String site3;
        URL url;
        HtmlGetter htmlGetter = new HtmlGetter();

        while(true) {
            site2 = "69";
            site3 = "is-this-implementation-of-shamos-hoey-algorithm-ok";
            url = new URL(site1 + site2 + "/" + site3);
            htmlGetter.setFileName("[" + site2 + "]" + site3 + ".html");
            htmlGetter.download(url);
            htmlGetter.parse();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

HtmlGetter.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils; 
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class HtmlGetter {
    private String fileName;

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void download(URL url) throws Exception {
        final InputStream in = url.openStream();
        final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

    public void parse() throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        String oneLine;
        String htmlTagRegex = "<(/)?([a-zA-Z]*)(\\s[a-zA-Z]*=[^>]*)?(\\s)*(/)?>";

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            oneLine = scanner.nextLine();
            if(oneLine.matches(".*<code>.*")) {
                while(scanner.hasNextLine()&&(!oneLine.matches(".*</code>.*"))) {
                    oneLine = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(oneLine.replaceAll(htmlTagRegex, ""));
                    System.out.println(oneLine);
                    oneLine = scanner.nextLine();
                    // This cannot handle such kind of a line which has <code> and </code> together.
                }
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String site1 = "http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/";
    String site2;
    String site3;
```

Why do define site1 as a final constant, but delay the other assignments until later? They should really be static finals for the class. Also some clearer names would not go amiss.

```
    URL url;
```

Declare them where they are used, don't declare them ahead of time.

```
    HtmlGetter htmlGetter = new HtmlGetter();

    while(true) {
        site2 = "69";
        site3 = "is-this-implementation-of-shamos-hoey-algorithm-ok";
        url = new URL(site1 + site2 + "/" + site3);
        htmlGetter.setFileName("[" + site2 + "]" + site3 + ".html");
        htmlGetter.download(url);
        htmlGetter.parse();
        break;
```

Why do you have a loop if you are just going to break out of it?
        }
    }

```
public void parse() throws Exception {
```

You shouldn't throw Exception, your specification should really only include the exceptions that'll actually be thrown

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    String oneLine;
    String htmlTagRegex = "<(/)?([a-zA-Z]*)(\\s[a-zA-Z]*=[^>]*)?(\\s)*(/)?>";
```

Parsing HTML by regex is asking for trouble. Instead, you'll find the task much easier if you grab a html parsing library and use that.

```
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        oneLine = scanner.nextLine();
        if(oneLine.matches(".*<code>.*")) {
```

You are just searching for a substring here, there isn't much point in using regex to do that.

```
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()&&(!oneLine.matches(".*</code>.*"))) {
```

If you insist on regex, use a single regex to capture the entire code tag.

```
                oneLine = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(oneLine.replaceAll(htmlTagRegex, ""));
                System.out.println(oneLine);
                oneLine = scanner.nextLine();
                // This cannot handle such kind of a line which has <code> and </code> together.
            }
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
        }
    }           
}
```

Using something like jsoup: http://jsoup.org/

```
Document question = Jsoup.connect("http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69").get();
Elements codes = question.select("code")
for(Element code: codes)
{
   System.out.println(code.text())
}
```